# Reading multiple columns as array field using Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I am reading a csv file and want to import the last 3 columns as an array.

The data look something like:

```
01/01/2020,   100.5,  Apple,   0.1,  0.2, 0.3 
02/01/2020,   373.0,  Banana,  7.5,  6.6, 2.1 
03/01/2020,   552.9,  Orange,  8.0,  1.2, 7.5 
....
```

Previously I managed this with Numpy using genfromtxt by defining the data's dtype:

```
mydtype = np.dtype([('Date', 'a10'),('Val', 'f8'),('Fruit', 'a10'),('ValArray', '3f8')
```

then calling numpy genfromtxt using that dtype:

```
Data = np.genfromtxt('My input file', dtype=mydtype, delimiter=',', autostrip=True)
```

This gave me a Numpy structured array with the fields 'Date', 'Val', 'Fruit', and 'ValArray',  where 'ValArray' is an array of arrays.

---

Now I would like to do the same process using Pandas read_csv but I find that it does not use the dtype in the same way as Numpy.

I defined a dtype suitable for Pandas:

```
myPandasdtype = {'Date': 'a10','Val':'f8','Fruit': 'a10', 'ValArray':'3f8'}
```

and used the Pandas read_csv as:

```
PData = PD.read_csv('My input file', dtype=myPandasdtype , sep=',',  header=None)
```

but found that Pandas gave me a dataframe having a date index, a float field, a string field and three more float fields.

However I would like the last three float fields to be read as an array of three floats, and to have the fields named using the dtype labels.

Is it possible to do this in Pandas?